# What is the function of "as" here?

Tags: grammar

I read this sentence in my workbook:

> Regaining the former glory **as** a port town in the Middle Ages, it is now a prosperous town.

I've tried to simplify this below:

> I regained the innocence **as** a boy.

What is the function of *as* here? Does this mean "I regained the innocence I had when I was a boy?

Comment: It could. It seems sort of oddly written. Can you share where you found it and maybe the rest of the paragraph if there is one?

Comment: It is from a book. "Regaining the former glory as a port town in the Middle Ages, it is now a prosperous town." I simplified this.

Comment: In the unsimplified version the meaning is more clear. The town had glory as a port town in the Middle Ages, when it was presumably of use to naval trade. Nowadays, it has _regained_ that glory, and is prosperous again (perhaps by being a port town again, or perhaps by some other means).

Comment: So this "as" is the same as the one in "I was cheerful as a boy."?

Comment: Essentially, yes. There's an element of _possessing_ a quality that is perhaps a tiny bit different (and could be made clearer by writing the possessive "its" rather than the definite article, as in _"Regaining **its** former glory..."_), but they're the same grammatically, yes.

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: My work book. So it's not a novel.

Comment: The original sentence seems a little strange to me, although I suppose I can guess what it means.  It might make more sense in context, but if there is no context, then I suppose not...

Comment: @snailboat I suspect most of us would write *regaining **its** former glory as* or *regaining the glory **it had** as*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regaining the former glory as a port town in the Middle Ages, it is now a prosperous town.

The word "as" could indicate the role, condition, or status. In this case, the phrase "as a port town" explains how the glory was. It was not glory by agriculture; it was glory established by exports and imports.

This usage of the word "as" adds an explanation to the object, the subject or the noun immediately before "as" in the sentence.